# Use Log4View to a folder with zipped logfiles

Tags: zip, logfiles, log4view

I tried to use `log4viewer` for the first time. So my question is basic-level. It is possible to set Log4view to a folder, which has zipped log-files in it? And if yes, how can I configure Log4view correctly? I tried but can't find an example of to do that.

```
c:\Folder1\zippedLogfiles001.zip
c:\Folder1\zippedLogfiles002.zip
c:\Folder1\zippedLogfiles003.zip (up to 300 logfiles)
...
```

I heard it is possible that Log4view can read automatically from a folder, so that it doesn't need to unzip the log files manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4View doesn't work with zipped log files. 
To open a log file with Log4View, it has to be a regular, uncompressed text or xml file.

Ulrich